# C++ character array doesn't take inputs of more than 4 characters

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a char array in C++ that will store a limited number of characters that I set (in this case 5). My program looks like this:

```
char name[5];

cout << "Enter 5 character name: ";
cin.getline(name, 5);

cout << name;
```

I defined a char variable named "name" and set it to store only 5 characters, but whenever I run the program and try to enter anything more than 4 characters, the program truncates anything longer than 4 characters. This happens even if I change the number of characters in the char definition or use a cin statement.

Comment: the last character is `\0`

Comment: Both `cin.getline(name, 5);` and `cout << name;` treats `name` as a null-terminated string, hence `char name[5];`, with those usages, contains (at most) 4 characters + null-terminator (`\0`). If you are trying to write/read more, you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Why can't you just use `std::string` so you don't have to worry about stuff like making space for the null terminator?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the null terminator character, it might also depend on the version of your C++ compiler, anyways reading the reference here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/...

It says:

> Extracts characters from the stream as unformatted input and stores them into s as a c-string, until either the extracted character is the delimiting character, or n characters have been written to s (including the terminating null character).

If it includes the null character terminator, then it should be reserved a place at the very end of the character array, that's why if you have a 5 characters char array, cin.getline fills in 4 only.

Comment: that is not a good reference site, try cppreference.com instead